# netlifyにCloud Firestoreの環境変数が反映されない

Tags: reactjs, api, firebase, netlify

ReactとmicroCMSとCloud Firestoreを使用してcafeサイトを作りました。 netlifyに使用している環境変数を設定してデプロイをしましたが、microCMSの環境変数は反映されていますが、Cloud Firestoreの環境変数が反映されません。

コードはgithubにのせています。(https://github.com/ookuraseiya/cafe)

いろいろ調べながら修正を試みていますが、一向に解決できません。
どなたかご教授お願いいたします

以下のサイトが、環境変数の設定方法とnetlifyのデプロイする手順です。（同じように行っています。） https://vainders-hands-on.jp/handson/YYr7rINTR0MxPEf0uHIH/6ghvP9aV86lhwpK0ZYJf#headline-id-2

Answer (score 0):

自力で解決できました！！！！！
ありがとうございました！！！！！！！！

Comment: もし解決したのであれば、事実をつたえるだけではなくて具体的な情報も記載してあると、似たような問題に遭遇した他のユーザーにも役立つと思います。

Comment: 落ち着いたら記事にしてここにURLをはろうと思います！